# On the mismatch between prediction results and probability in SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning

Why does the result of the prediction function not correspond to the result of the probability function?
I think the prediction result should be 3.help me plz

```
    x = [[1,2,3],[11,18,16],[22,27,26],[33,34,39],[3,3,9],[13,24,49]]
    y = [1,1,2,3,4,3]
    clf = SVC(probability=True,kernel='rbf', 
    degree=2,gamma=0.1,random_state=2,decision_function_shape="ovo")
    clf.fit(x,y)
    print(clf.predict([[10,15,13]]))
    print(clf.predict_proba([[10,15,13]]))
```

[1]
[[0.23456566 0.23289301 0.29844741 0.23409392]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about it too much. Trust the `.predict` more as the `.predict_proba` could be inconsistant with `.predict`. you can check the same in official docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) in the description of `probability` parameter.